# Dimension too large with long caption?

Tags: errors, captions, dimensions

I'm having trouble with a figure with a long caption that fills most of (but not all of) a page. Here's a MWE that reproduces the issue with lorem ipsum text that's about the same length.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
    \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultricies neque risus, ut rutrum elit maximus sed. Aliquam posuere auctor justo eget scelerisque. Donec non justo a dolor gravida consectetur. Integer volutpat velit velit, in venenatis metus hendrerit sit amet. Curabitur imperdiet ullamcorper nisi, non ullamcorper nibh accumsan in. Ut luctus nisl eget eleifend pulvinar. Sed diam nibh, mattis elementum velit ut, eleifend tincidunt mauris. Pellentesque venenatis semper odio gravida ultrices. Vivamus ac molestie ante. Fusce pellentesque finibus enim, nec congue diam euismod in. Nunc eu tempor purus. Curabitur eu arcu vitae massa laoreet semper in varius tortor. Maecenas nec mauris pretium, pulvinar lacus a, maximus lectus. Donec sapien odio, suscipit eu dui vitae, pellentesque pharetra justo. Etiam pellentesque blandit porta.
    Ut a faucibus lacus. Aenean quis nibh mi. Fusce eu risus massa. Praesent faucibus justo vitae fermentum elementum. Nam at nisi at leo tincidunt tristique. Sed eros libero, elementum vel velit ut, fringilla luctus nibh. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Cras iaculis orci at vestibulum congue. Ut scelerisque quam est, nec fermentum dolor molestie sit amet. Sed fermentum porttitor lorem, vel condimentum mauris ultrices fermentum. Donec pharetra, ipsum sit amet imperdiet interdum, neque neque semper diam, semper suscipit metus turpis non risus. Curabitur quam sapien, aliquet eget tellus eget, laoreet lobortis felis.
    Sed nec lacinia odio. Sed massa mauris, pharetra nec sapien a, rhoncus luctus ligula. Aliquam nec orci et libero elementum maximus. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc malesuada sed mauris quis faucibus. Phasellus tincidunt scelerisque neque sed dapibus. Etiam vitae ex quis tortor placerat fringilla a in turpis. Integer sit amet diam tincidunt, imperdiet sem id, facilisis massa. Duis molestie felis at tortor tincidunt, a blandit quam ultrices. Nunc aliquam tristique est et gravida.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultricies neque risus, ut rutrum elit maximus sed. Aliquam posuere auctor justo eget scelerisque. Donec non justo a dolor gravida consectetur. Integer volutpat velit velit, in venenatis metus hendrerit sit amet. Curabitur imperdiet ullamcorper nisi, non ullamcorper nibh accumsan in. Ut luctus nisl eget eleifend pulvinar. Sed diam nibh, mattis elementum velit ut, eleifend tincidunt mauris. Pellentesque venenatis semper odio gravida ultrices. Vivamus ac molestie ante. Fusce pellentesque finibus enim, nec congue diam euismod in. Nunc eu tempor purus. Curabitur eu arcu vitae massa laoreet semper in varius tortor. Maecenas nec mauris pretium, pulvinar lacus a, maximus lectus. Donec sapien odio, suscipit eu dui vitae, pellentesque pharetra justo. Etiam pellentesque blandit porta.
    Ut a faucibus lacus. Aenean quis nibh mi. Fusce eu risus massa. Praesent faucibus justo vitae fermentum elementum. Nam at nisi at leo tincidunt tristique. Sed eros libero, elementum vel velit ut, fringilla luctus nibh. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Cras iaculis orci at vestibulum congue. Ut scelerisque quam est, nec fermentum dolor molestie sit amet. Sed fermentum porttitor lorem, vel condimentum mauris
    }
\end{figure}  

\end{document}
```

This gives me the following error with both pdflatex or xelatex 2022:

```
! Dimension too large.
\caption@slc ...ke {#1}{#2}}\ifdim \wd \@tempboxa 
                                                  >\caption@width \endgroup ...
l.14     }
          
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.


LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 12.06998pt on input line 15.
```

If I comment out the last line beginning with "Ut a faucibus", the issue goes away. I tried setting the caption width manually with `\captionsetup{width=0.8\linewidth}` but this doesn't work. I think caption@width is presumably the offending length, but I don't understand.

Comment: use `\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}` (or set this locally) as you don't want to have this on one line, the check is unneeded.

Comment: Oh, wonderful, that fixes it. Thank you! (I'm new here, is there something I'm supposed to do to accept this as the answer? I don't see how to do it for a comment)

Comment: I added an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
 \usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
```

(or set this locally) as you don't want to have the caption on one line, the check is unneeded.